# Lint/AmbiguousOperator: Ambiguous negative number operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I am using [rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) gem. 
Following is my factorybot code.

```
factory :cut, class: CutSetting do

  maximum_length 100
  max_colors_cut_together -1

end
```

Rubocop give the following errors for negative value -1.

Lint/AmbiguousOperator: Ambiguous negative number operator. Parenthesize the method arguments if it's surely a negative number operator, or add a whitespace to the right of the - if it should be a subtraction. (https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#method-invocation-parens)

How to solve this problem. PLEASE HELP ME :(.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that static attributes are deprecated in FactoryBot. In the next version you'll need to use brackets `{}` around all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_colors_cut_together -1` is actually ruby's syntax sugar for method invocation `max_colors_cut_together(-1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. llya Konyukhov's and your answer both are working.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add more to Rubocop's error description, it's clear and comprehensive. Adding brackets to -1:

```
max_colors_cut_together { -1 }
```

should eliminate that error.

See this [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/factory_bot) as a quick guide on factory_bot patterns.